# running exe in windows server core on docker windows container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, windows-container, server-core

i run dockerfile

```
#servercore its mine tag
FROM  servercore 
COPY ./prog./work/prog
WORKDIR /work
CMD ["cmd.exe", "/c", "start /b C:\\work\\prog\\prog.exe"]
```

then inside of container i type tasklist and see [image: tasklist]
in this case my program doesn`t work

Also i tried to run exe inside windows servercore with terminal
[image: tasklist]
and my program is fully working, which can be seen in memory in the task manager

How  can і run exe by dockerfile ?

Comment: define your executable as `ENTRYPOINT`

Comment: i replace CMD to ENTRYPOINT but i have same result like on first picture (10 000 k)

Comment: So your program is indeed running on startup, isn't it? If it doesn't function correctly on a freshly started system, its probably a problem of your application and not of docker. Does it have any dependencies on other services/resources that need to be initialized first?

Comment: my program dont have any dependencies on other services/resources that need to be initialized first. Also i show second srceenshot, if i run exe inside servercore in terminal program.exe all is good, program work

Comment: but my task is to make it work correctly when starting the docker container without further intervention

Comment: Well, then you have to find out, why your task doesn't work as expected when started immediately after start. The entrypoint is just calling the provided executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might have happened because when you are trying to start your app.exe from different path then your app. It might throw some exception because app does not see all dependencies/resources etc.
You should change your workdir from `WORKDIR /work` to `WORKDIR /work/prog` and in CMD ./prog.exe.